# How to set width of a p:column in a p:dataTable in PrimeFaces 3.0?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.0-M3 and I have a `<p:dataTable>` with two columns in it. I want the first column to be fixed at a width of 20px. The other column can use whatever space is left over.

Here are screenshots of what I'm currently getting:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

The first `<p:column>` seems to be ignoring the `style` setting that should have limited the width. It is sized way too big for the tiny coloured square that is the only content inside it and then the other column is pushed too far to the right.

Here is more of my Facelet code:

```
<p:dataTable
        id="dataTableExpressions"
        value="#{catconBean.userDefinedExpressionDataModel}"
        var="currentRow"
        emptyMessage="!! EMPTY TABLE MESSAGE !!"
        selection="#{catconBean.userDefinedExpressionToEdit}"
        selectionMode="single">
    <p:ajax 
            event="rowSelect" 
            listener="#{catconBean.onUserDefinedExpressionRowSelect}"
            update=":toolbarForm:catconToolbar" />
    <p:ajax 
            event="rowUnselect" 
            listener="#{catconBean.onUserDefinedExpressionRowUnselect}"
            update=":toolbarForm:catconToolbar" />

    <p:column id="paletteColor" style="width:20px;">
        <h:panelGroup 
                layout="block"
                rendered="#{not empty currentRow.paletteColor}"
                style="width:16px;height:16px;border:thin;border-style:solid;border-color:black;background-color:##{currentRow.paletteColor.RGB};" />
        <h:panelGroup 
                layout="block"
                rendered="#{empty currentRow.paletteColor}"
                style="width:16px;height:16px;border:thin;border-style:dashed;border-color:red;background-color:white;text-align:center;">
            <h:outputText value="?" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:column>

    <p:column id="name">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.catcon_label_CategoryName}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText 
            value="#{currentRow.name}"
            style="#{not currentRow.definitionComplete ? 'color:red;' : ''}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Can anyone tell me how to modify my Facelet code to make the first column have a fixed width of 20px?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In PrimeFaces 3.0, that style get applied on the generated inner `<div>` of the table cell, not on the `<td>` as you (and I) would expect. The following example should work out for you:

```html
<p:dataTable styleClass="myTable">
```

with

```
.myTable td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 20px;
}
```

In PrimeFaces 3.5 and above, it should work exactly the way you coded and expected.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't seem to have any effect. The only other change I made was to remove the `style="width:20px;"` from my `<p:column>` declaration, which also had no effect.

Comment: There it is...  Works with your solution under Firefox 4.0.1, but does not work under IE 7. Unfortunately for me, IE 7 is the browser being used in the target environment.

Comment: That old browser does indeed not support all modern selectors. Consider IE7.js: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ Or report an issue to PF guys that you want the `columnClasses` back in the `<p:dataTable>` like as `<h:dataTable>` has (that was the first what I looked at, but to my surprise it didn't support that attribute) see also http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1797

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps they will be able to suggest alternative and IE7-compatible ways to achieve this requirement. As far I don't see any, but I'd however be curious to their answer.

Comment: I've started a thread here: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15031

Comment: That thread is a wormhole into a dark abyss without solutions.

Comment: Besides, these solutions are crap. What if you need varying columns?

Comment: Just don't use a jurassic library version if you don't want crap?

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me

```
<p:column headerText="name" style="width:20px;"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, this was not working

```
<p:column headerText="" width="25px" sortBy="#{row.key}">
```

But this worked:

```
<p:column headerText="" width="25" sortBy="#{row.key}">
```

Comment: (Still valid:) In Primefaces 6.1 attribute width without a unit means px, with unit % it means percentage of table width.

Comment: % is not working for me. I was able to use e.g. `width="40"` and `width="60"` like they were %'s though.

Comment: The reason is that PF adds the "px" to the width attribute, so in the first case you got `style="width:10pxpx"`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what browser you're using, but according to w3schools.com, nth-child and nth-last-child do now work on MSIE 8.  I don't know about 9.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp will give you more info.

Answer (score 1):

can you try

```
<p:column width="20">
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline styling would work in any case

```
  <p-column field="Quantity" header="Qté" [style]="{'width':'48px'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following (in V 3.5) and it worked like a charm:

```
<p:column headerText="name" width="20px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @BalusC 's answer. You also need to set width of headers. In my case, below css can only apply to my table's column width.

```
.myTable td:nth-child(1),.myTable th:nth-child(1) {
   width: 20px;
}
```