# How to set width and margin of <p:column> in a <p:dataTable> ? primefaces

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.4.2 and I have to use  `<p:dataTable>`. I want fixe the width of the  first column to less than 5 px.
for that  I created a css class :

```
.myTableFlux td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 5px !important;
}
```

this is my table :

```
<p:dataTable  value="#{bean.listFlux}" var="list" styleClass="myTableFlux">
    <p:column headerText="Status" >
        <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/so#{list.i}.jpg" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Nom">
        <h:outputText value="#{list.name}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

the problem is that I can not go below 5 px.

here is the image that I want to have as a result
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7434572/617373

Comment: I can set width less than 5px (first image). how can i delete the margins ? @Daniel

Comment: I guess that `margin:0px;` or ``margin:1px;``

Comment: you can simply override all the style using inline style.you can find the style properties via using the firebug in Mozilla, or inspect element

Comment: Your initial question is confusing. `5px` is not the same as `5%`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, the `width`-Attribute on the `p:column` tag works with PrimeFaces 3.4:

```
<p:column width="3" headerText="longlong">
  <h:outputText value="xyz" />
</p:column>
```

This code will display like this:

[image]

**Edit**:
Found a solution to style the padding of certain columns:

```
<style>
    .ui-datatable td:nth-child(1) div.ui-dt-c {
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
  }
</style>
```

PrimeFaces can be a little tricky. You have to track down where the attribute comes from, and overwrite the specific styleClasses.